# Are one point compactifications topologically invariant?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

More precisely: are one point compactifications $X^+$ and $Y^+$ of homeomorphic locally compact Hausdorff spaces $X$ and $Y$ again homeomorphic?

Kindly appreciated,

Aris

Comment: I just figured it out on my whiteboard. I think it is true. Interested in what I think to be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Fix a homeomorphism $f\colon X\to Y$. There is exactly one way to extend it to $X^+$ and $Y^+$. Now recall that $U\subseteq X^+$ is open if and only if $U\subseteq X$ is open, or $X\setminus U$ is compact, and similarly for open subsets of $Y^+$.

Show that in either case the image of an open set is open, and the preimage of an open set is open.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:X\to Y$ be the homeomorphism between the two locally compact Hausdorff spaces. Since $f$ is proper (preimages of compact sets are again compact), it can be extended to a continuous map $f^+:X^+\to Y^+$, by sending $\infty_X$ to $\infty_Y$. But the same holds for its inverse $g:Y\to X$. Now clearly $g^+\circ f^+=Id_{X^+}$ and $f^+\circ g^+=Id_{Y^+}$.